# ExtendedFloatingActionButton - how to achieve same height when button is extended as when it's shrank

Tags: android, android-button, floating-action-button, material-components-android, material-components

I'm using latest material components - 1.1.0-beta01.

When ExtendedFloatingActionButton expands, its height also reduces.

[image: fab shrinked]

[image: fab expanded]

Here is how xml layout looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/main_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="56dp"
       android:text="Text"
       android:textColor="#02220D"
       android:backgroundTint="#F2C203"
       style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
       android:textStyle="normal"
       android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:iconTint="#02220D"
       app:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
       app:iconPadding="10dp"
       android:insetLeft="0dp"
       android:insetBottom="0dp"
       android:insetTop="0dp"
       android:insetRight="0dp"
       />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to set min and max height, but it didn't work. Any idea how to achieve the same height when button is expanded and shrank?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` is a `MaterialButton`.
You can use the `android:minHeight` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    ../>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can define a custom style:

```
 <style name="CustomExtendedFloating"  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon">
    <item name="android:minHeight">56dp</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said, I already tried to set min height, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've just tried it as you can see in the image attached. In your code I can't see it and you are using the `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"` with has a default `android:minHeight=48dp`

Comment: I did try it although I didn't post it in code. Using "style" was the problem as you pointed out, I removed it and it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `app:collapsedSize` property with your required size

`app:collapsedSize="56dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoded value use the one provided by the material library :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:minHeight="@dimen/design_fab_size_normal"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting, according to the spec for FAB and Extended FAB, in the extended state, it's not as tall. https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#specs